# В чем причина ошибки AttributeError: partially initialized module ... (most likely due to a circular import)?

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

полный трейс ошибки

```
test-task-for-victory-api-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     exec(code, run_globals)
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/app/victory/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     import uvicorn
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     from uvicorn.config import Config
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 1, in <module>
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     import asyncio
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     from .base_events import *
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     import concurrent.futures
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 7, in <module>
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     import logging
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/app/victory/logging.py", line 5, in <module>
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     from loguru import logger
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/loguru/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     from ._logger import Core as _Core
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/loguru/_logger.py", line 88, in <module>
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     from . import _asyncio_loop, _colorama, _defaults, _filters
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/loguru/_asyncio_loop.py", line 27, in <module>
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     get_task_loop, get_running_loop = load_loop_functions()
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/loguru/_asyncio_loop.py", line 11, in load_loop_functions
test-task-for-victory-api-1  |     get_running_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop
test-task-for-victory-api-1  | AttributeError: partially initialized module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'get_running_loop' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

docker file

```
FROM python:3.9.6-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  gcc libturbojpeg0 \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN pip install poetry

# Configuring poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false

RUN mkdir /app

# Copying requirements of a project
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock /app/

WORKDIR /app/

# Installing requirements
RUN poetry install
# Removing gcc
RUN apt-get purge -y \
  gcc \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copying actually application
COPY . .

CMD python migrate.py && python victory
```

файл запуска

```
import uvicorn

from victory.settings import settings


def main() -> None:
    """Entrypoint of the application."""
    uvicorn.run(
        "victory.web.application:get_app",
        workers=settings.workers_count,
        host=settings.host,
        port=settings.port,
        reload=settings.reload,
        log_level=settings.log_level.value.lower(),
        factory=True,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

локально все работает

Answer (score 0):

Ты вроде бы создаешь workdir /app/, но в докере копируешь в root:
`COPY . .`
попробуй копировать в /app/

Comment: но вторая . же означает /app т.к. WORKDIR /app/ . изменение на /app/ ничего не чинит

Answer (score 0):

Примерный перевод ошибки

> AttributeError: partially initialized module ... has no attribute ... (most likely due to a circular import)

- "частично инициализированный модуль ... не имеет атрибута ... (скорее всего из-за циклического импорта)". Смысл циклического импорта в том, что какой-то модуль импортирует сам себя напрямую, или через другие модули, в итоге импорт как бы "закольцовывается".

Смотрим по трэйсбэку, я добавил комментарии к нему:

```
# тут модуль, который импортировал и запустил ваш модуль
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
        return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
# ваш модуль
    File "/app/victory/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
        import uvicorn
# дальше uvicorn и импортируемые им модули, в том числе asyncio
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from uvicorn.config import Config
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 1, in <module>
        import asyncio
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .base_events import *
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
        import concurrent.futures
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 7, in <module>
        import logging
# ВНЕЗАПНО, снова модуль из вашего кода
    File "/app/victory/logging.py", line 5, in <module>
        from loguru import logger
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/loguru/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from ._logger import Core as _Core
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/loguru/_logger.py", line 88, in <module>
        from . import _asyncio_loop, _colorama, _defaults, _filters
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/loguru/_asyncio_loop.py", line 27, in <module>
        get_task_loop, get_running_loop = load_loop_functions()
# Снова идет обращение к asyncio, получается циклический импорт
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/loguru/_asyncio_loop.py", line 11, in load_loop_functions
        get_running_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop
    AttributeError: partially initialized module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'get_running_loop' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Циклический импорт возник из-за того, что в вашем коде есть модуль с именем logging.py (`/app/victory/logging.py`), который  импортируется из стандартной библиотеки вместо стандартного модуля `logging`. И получается, что импортируется `asyncio`, внутри себя он где-то глубоко пытается импортировать стандартный модуль `logging`, но вместо этого модуля импортируется ваш модуль, который использует `loguru`, который внутри себя опять использует `asyncio` - получается бесконечный цикл импортов.

Проблема решается переименованием вашего модуля `logging.py` во что-то другое.

В целом, наиболее частая причина ошибки `partially initialized module ... (most likely due to a circular import)` - совпадение имени файла в своем коде с именем какого-то из стандартных или сторонних модулей, которые используются из вашего кода.

Иногда даже основной модуль называют как модуль, который из него импортируется. Например, основной модуль назван `asyncio.py`, из него идет импорт `import asyncio` - сразу же идет циклический импорт, потому что модуль фактически импортирует сам себя (а не модуль `asyncio` стандартной библиотеки). Но это самый простой случай.

Другая причина такой ошибки: в своем коде два модуля импортируют друг друга. Это уже архитектурная проблема, решается перестройкой архитектуры проекта, например (в простом случае) выносом каких-то общих частей (функций, классов) в отдельный модуль, либо применением приёма/принципа инверсии зависимостей (Dependency Inversion из SOLID), опять же с выносом общего "интерфейса" (абстрактного класса) наружу, в отдельный модуль, при этом модули перестают зависеть друг от друга напрямую, а зависят от модуля с вынесенным интерфейсом.