# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pickle' has no attribute 'dump'

Tags: python

Помогите. Делал задание по учебнику **A Byte of Python**. Точно такой же код, но выдает ошибку. Пытался искать

```
# Filename: pickling.py
import pickle

# the name of the file where we will store the object
shoplistfile = "shoplist.data"
# the list of things to buy
shoplist = ["apple", "mango", "carrot"]

# Write to the file
f = open(shoplistfile, "wb")
pickle.dump(shoplist, f)  # dump the object to a file
f.close()

del shoplist  # destroy the shoplist variable

# Read back from the storage
f = open(shoplistfile, "rb")
storedlist = pickle.load(f)  # load the object from the file
print(storedlist)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/busterenko/Desktop/fgdg/pickle.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "/Users/busterenko/Desktop/fgdg/pickle.py", line 11, in <module>
    pickle.dump(shoplist, f)  # dump the object to a file
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pickle' has no attribute 'dump' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Куча похожих вопросов есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+AttributeError%3A+partially+initialized+module. Например, тут я подробно расписал почему такая проблема может возникать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1518967/1365

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ошибка, которую вы видите, связана с тем, что ваш файл называется `pickle.py`, что совпадает с именем стандартного модуля Python pickle. Когда вы пытаетесь импортировать модуль `pickle`, Python сначала ищет файл с таким именем в текущем каталоге, и поэтому он импортирует ваш собственный файл `pickle.py`, а не стандартный модуль.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, вы можете переименовать ваш файл `pickle.py` во что-то другое.

Comment: не помогло также

Comment: Должно было помочь, по крайней мере ошибка должна была стать другой. Забавно, кстати, что прям в комментарии в вашем коде написано, что ваш файл должен был называться `pickling.py`, а судя по ошибке вы его назвали именно `pickle.py`.

Comment: а все нормально просто старые ошибки видел все работает

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что в рабочей папке есть файл с именем `pickle.py`. Когда вы пишете `import pickle`, система испортирует именно этот файл, а не стандартный модуль.

Отличие от ответа @armen-legran в том, что не важно как называется запускаемый файл. Важно, чтобы `pickle.py` не существовало.

А так как у вас сам скрипт называется pickle.py, то он пытается импортировать сам себя. Осюда и приписка `most likely due to a circular import` - циклический импорт.

Comment: Предположение интересное, но трейс начинается именно с файла `/Users/busterenko/Desktop/fgdg/pickle.py`, если бы запущенный файл назывался по-другому, то и трейс бы начинался с запущенного файла с другим названием.